# scrapy get text from image title attribute inside a nested table

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am new to scrapy and I am trying to get the text value from the title attribute of a image inside a nested table. Below is a sample of a table

```
<html>
     <body>
      <div id=yw1>
      <table id="x">
        <thead></thead>
         <tbody>
          <tr>
           <td>
             <table id="y">
               <thead></thead>
               <tbody>
                <tr>
                 <td><img src=".." title="Sample"></td>
                 <td></td>
                </tr>
               </tbody>
             </table>
           </td>
           <td></td>
          </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

I use the following scrapy code to get the text from the title attribute.

```
def parse(self, response):
    transfers = Selector(response).xpath('//*[@id="yw1"]/table/tbody/tr')

    for transfer in transfers:
        item = TransfermarktItem()
        item['naam'] = transfer.xpath('td[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/img/@title/text()').extract()
        item['positie'] = transfer.xpath('td[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a/text()').extract()
        item['leeftijd'] = transfer.xpath('td[2]/text()').extract()
        yield item
```

For some reason the text value of the title attribute is not extracted. What is it I am doing wrong??

Cheers!

Comment: Why aren't you using something like PyQuery or BeautifulSoup?

Comment: is `positie` working?

Comment: looks like it shouldn't, now to get `naam`, use `//img/@title`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can just use

```
        item['naam'] = transfer.xpath(
           'td[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/img/@title'
        )
```

This will return a list.

`text()` is not useful for getting tag attribute values.
`extract()` I think can also be omitted here.

EDIT:
some more possibility, if the above is still not working, would be the `tbody` problem, i.e. http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/firefox.html. You can try like that:
`td[1]/table//tr[1]/td[1]/img/@title`

If that doesn't help, then based on the data we've got here, I think I'm out of ideas :)

Comment: This doesn't seems to work :-( Still getting no value returned.

Comment: When I loaded this via lxml.html I got the expected result with this xpath. Do you have result for "positie" and "leeftijd"?

Comment: I got the value from "leeftijd" but thats because it is not within the nested table. You used lxml.html? Could you share this?

Comment: No magic there, just wanted to test this particular xpath: https://gist.github.com/radoslawroszkowiak/8ecf53c618488a7bf3e9. It works, whereas your version with `text()` does not. Are you sure your problem is really related to xpath, then?

Comment: Actually one more thing comes to my mind. Maybe you could try xpath without `tbody`, like that: `td[1]/table//tr[1]/td[1]/img/@title`?

Comment: losing tbody seems to work, but why? could you pls explain.

Comment: Some browsers (Firefox, I think Chrome too, I don't know how about the rest) add <tbody> to the table, even if the original HTML does not contain it. So if you inspect page you can see <tbody> as it's added by the browser, but when your crawler visits the page, there's no <tbody>

Comment: Aahh never knew that. Thx the info.